# How to choose a deep learning model?

Tags: deep-learning

I have split the database available into 70% training, 15% validation, and 15% test. I have trained the model and got the following results:
training accuracy 100%, validation accuracy 97.61%, test accuracy 96.74%

In another trial for training the model, I got the following results:
Training accuracy 100%, validation accuracy 97.61%, test accuracy 98.91%

Although the training and validation accuracy in both cases are the same, the test accuracy is different.

Which model should I choose, the first case in which the the test accuracy is lower than the validation? or the second case in which the test is higher than than the validation?

Comment: Your question reads as if you have split the database once, then tried out your one arrangement of training, validation, and test data on two different neural nets.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I have used holdout validation for splitting the database once into training, validation, and test data. I have tested the same network under different parameters and different initial conditions, not two different networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each one of these trials is a [point estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_estimation). Every time that you run the process you are describing, the model is trained, validated and tested over a slightly different version of the underlying dataset and will be giving you different performance figures.

But, if you collect all of these performance figures together, you would form a "population" of point estimates which you can then use to infer the sort of best-case / worst-case performance figures for a given model.

This sampling of the performance under slightly different training and validation datasets (based of course on a percentage split) is exactly what [k-fold validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) does.

At the end of this process, you get $k$ performance measurements that, as a "population of numbers", will have a mean and standard deviation which can be used to gauge the performance of the model better. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#/media/File:Confusion_matrix.png) for a very simple example).

Just using k-fold validation however is not a remedy for having a limited or bad quality dataset.

For much more detail, please see chapter 5 in [this book](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/book.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what A_A said about point estimates -- if you have a fixed size database, and you want to really wring out which candidate training approach works best, you should probably do multiple trials, each with its own random splitting of the data base.

Then look at which approach succeeds most often, and by how much.